# How do I convert this into a zoo object in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, zoo

I have a very big dataset which is a data frame containing Date/Time in 1 column and closing price in the next.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qFQO.png)
I am using the following code:

```r
read.zoo(df,tz="GMT",format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M")
```

but this is shown:

```
Error in read.zoo(df, tz = "GMT", format = "%d.%m.%Y %H:%M") : 
  index has 28290 bad entries at data rows: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42...
```

What should I do?

The image is part of my dataframe

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Pictures of data are not very useful.

Comment: I don't know how

Comment: The link I provided shows many ways to create reproducible examples.